# Post form to void controller action without getting redirected afterwards

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authorization

This is my view from which I'm posting the form:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Register", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { id="frmRegister", @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary("", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    <div class="col-md-8">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Username, new { @class = "form-control form-input", placeholder = "ID" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Username, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-8">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Mail, new { @class = "form-control form-input", placeholder = "Mail" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Mail, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-8">
        @Html.PasswordFor(x => x.Password, new { @class = "form-control form-input", placeholder = "Parolă" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Password, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-8">
        @Html.PasswordFor(x => x.ConfirmPassword, new { @class = "form-control form-input", placeholder = "Confirmă parola" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.ConfirmPassword, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
    <input type="submit" id="btnGetConfCodeView" onclick="ShowConfCodeInput()" style="margin-top: 7px; margin-bottom: -5px" value="Fă-l!" class="btn btn-info" />
    <input type="button" id="btnCloseRegister" style="margin-top: 7px; margin-bottom: -5px" value="Las'" class="btn btn-default" />
}
```

And I'm using the action to store the inputted data:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public void Register(RegisterViewModel viewModel)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var user = new User
            {
                Username = viewModel.Username,
                Mail = viewModel.Mail,
                Password = viewModel.Password,
                MemberSince = DateTime.Now
            };
            Session["currentUser"] = user;
        }
    }
```

And after this action executes, I get redirected to */Account/Register* path. I want this to not happen, is it possible?

Comment: And what would you like to happen?

Comment: I would want the action to perform its logic, and the page to remain unchanged.

Comment: You should return a result in *Register* method or plan another application logic. this is somewhat obscure.

Answer (score 2):

It is going to show you blank screen with the url `Account/Register` since you are returning void from your HttpPost action method.

Ideally, you should be doing the [PRG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get) pattern.

**POST - REDIRECT-GET**

1. The form is displayed that asks the user for some input.
2. When the user submits the form, the code does some business logic/transaction (Save some thing to db etc). After successfully doing that, Send a 302 response to browser.
3. The [302](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_302) response tells the browser to issue a totally new GET request to the url provided by the server.In MVC, We can use `RedirectToAction` method to send the 302 response to the browser.

So your code will be

```
[HttpPost]
public void Register(RegisterViewModel viewModel)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
       // to do  :Save 
      return RedirectToAction("SuccesfullyRegistered","Account");
    }
    return View(viewModel);
}
```

So when user submits the form, we will save the user and send a 302 response to the browser and browser will issue a request to `Account/SuccessfullyRegistered` action method.

The PRG pattern prevents the duplicate form submission issue when user reloads the new view.

Answer (score 1):

Based upon your comment, you should use Ajax Helper or jquery to submit your form via ajax. [Working with Ajax Helper in ASP.NET MVC](http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/.net/working-with-ajax-helper-in-asp.net-mvc.htm) is a good tutorial of using Ajax Helper and there are lots of questions in stackoverflow about using jquery to submit a form. It's up to you to employ one of them. It seems that Ajax Helper is more easier to use.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to fire and forget the POST request of a form submit, then you can add an invisible *iframe* and let the *target* attribute of your form point to that iframe. Then the content of the reply to the POST will land there and the user won't see it since the iframe is hidden.

Your iframe definition could look like this:

```
<iframe id="nulframe" name="nulframe" style="width:0;height:0;border:0; border:none;" />
```

and you would add the target attribute to the first line of your code like this:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Register", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { id="frmRegister", @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form", target = "nulframe" }))
```

You could even handle the *load* event of the iframe to get signalled when the POST is completed.